# My array wont splice

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, splice

It does everything in the method (eg alert/div loads) but the splice doesn't work. So what I'm trying to do is when the user clicks the "remove" button, that specific video is removed from the array.

Code:

```
function updateFavourite(video) {
    document.getElementById("favourite").onclick = function () {
        blacklist[video["id"]] = true;
        myfavourite.push(video);
        var html =
        "<input class='removeButton' value='Remove' type='button' />" +
        "<li class=\"saved\">" +
            "<img class= \"img-rounded\" src=\"{0}\"/>" +
            "<p><b title=\"{2}\"><a class=\"extendedLink\" href=\"javascript:watchHistoricVideo(\'{1}\');\"><span></span>{2}</a></b><br>" +
            "by {3}<br>" +
            "{4} | {5} views</p>" +
            "</li>";

        $("#myfavourite").prepend(html.format(video["thumbnail"],
        video["id"],
        video["title"],
        video["uploader"],
        video["length"],
        video["views"]));
        $("#myfavourite .removeButton").click(function () {
            myfavourite.splice(video, 1);
            setVideoF(video);
            alert("Removed");
            document.getElementById("myfavourite").innerHTML = '<div id="myfavourite"></div>';
            $("#loadFavourite").trigger('click');
        });
        setVideoF(video);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you not already ask that question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894835/how-do-i-splice-my-array

Comment: Also how do you know that "My array wont splice"?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

first `splice` argument has to be an Integer - index of the element you want to remove

obviously you are passing an object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just remove the `video` object you can do the following as you need the index of it in the array first (as doodeec as said)...

```
function Remove(arr, obj) {
    var index = arr.indexOf(obj);

    if (index != -1) {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        throw new Error("Not in array")
    }
};
```

Just call `Remove(myfavourite, video);` that should sort it.

Comment: I added an alert box and it is apparently splicing, but when I refresh the page it is still there.